# LightSlider картинки с фиксированной высотой не влезают

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать галерею где у картинок фиксированная высота(но разная ширина), задал картинкам высоту 200, все нормально, но когда подключаю слайдер последняя картинка просто не влезает. Я так понял, что плагин задает не правильную ширину контейнера.

Как сделать чтобы картинки влезали с одинаковой высотой, но с разной шириной? по идее параметр autoWidth: true должен с эти справляться.

```
<ul id="lightslider">
    <li>
        <img height="200" src="http://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img height="200" src="http://picsum.photos/300/300" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img height="200" src="http://picsum.photos/200/200" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
    autoWidth: true
});
```

ссылка на код:
https://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/5208/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery округляет ширину!!! Вот у первой картинки ширина 133.33 а jquery округляет до 133, вот и получается что не влезает. Поменял везде в плагине .width() на [0].getBoundingClientRect().width и parseInt на parseFloat.